# Angular button in table

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom

I want to put the functionality of the 'prompt dialog' button in one of the tables cells. The catch is that the table cells are created and accessed only through JavaScript.

Link: https://codepen.io/walkerdude5/pen/JxjgqP?editors=1010

HTML:

```
<table>
<tbody id="example2">
</tbody>
</table>

<!-- what I want to be able to do -->
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl" ng-app="MyApp">
    <button ng-click="showPrompt($event)">
      Prompt Dialog
    </button>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
angular.module('MyApp', ['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages', 'material.svgAssetsCache'])
.controller('AppCtrl', function($compile, $scope, $mdDialog) {
  $scope.showPrompt = function(ev) {
    var confirm = $mdDialog.prompt()
      .title('Note Editor')
      .placeholder('New Note')
      .targetEvent(ev)
      .ok('Save')
      .cancel('Discard');
    $mdDialog.show(confirm).then(function(result) {
      $scope.variable = 'update note function'
    });
  };
});
    table = document.getElementById('example2');
     tr = table.insertRow(0);
     tr.insertCell(0);
     tr.insertCell(1);
     tr = table.insertRow(0);
     tr.insertCell(0);
     tr.insertCell(1);
    table.rows[0].cells[0].innerHTML='dummyContent1';
    table.rows[1].cells[0].innerHTML='dummyContent2';
    table.rows[0].cells[1].innerHTML='dummyContent3';

    var angularTD = table.rows[1].cells[1];
      //prompt dialog functionality in this cell
```

Comment: You should write your table code within the scope of AppCtrl and just put the button code into one of the table elements. Strongly suggest _not_ using `document.getElementById` and constructing the table inside the controller - it's too complicated and definitely not an "AngularJS" approach. Much easier to just write your table code in the html.

Comment: I get that but I have some constraints where the size of the table is determined by websocket data so I need to be able to create a cell and add the AngularJS button code within that cell